# Attribute Caching does not appear to work?

Tags: laravel

I wish to cache my hash of an attribute, via:

```
protected function hashedMediableId(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(function () {
            $hashId = new HashId();
            var_dump('running hash...');

            return $hashId->encode($this->mediable_id);
        })->shouldCache();
    }
```

But when I use `tinker` to check, I'm getting the `var_dump` every time I access the attribute. Why?

Comment: Well i tried and it's only called once, what do you type in tinker ?